# Cannot find reference 'ximgproc' in '__init__.py

Tags: opencv, opencv-contrib

i want to use `cv2.ximgproc` module.
this is add-on module at `Opencv`
but there is a problem to load module.

I tried `pip install opencv-contrib-python` but it doesn't work.
to be precise its already installed but can't not find `cv2.ximgproc` module.

```
import cv2  

...  

cv2.ximgproc.thinning( ... )
```

that's my import section.

So, I tried paste source file from OpenCV github
but there is only C++ source..
( sometimes `.py` file exist. but that is not file I need. )

Comment: can you include the code you use ti import & use `ximgproc`?

Comment: Are you sure you installed in the same environment with your project workspace?

Comment: @Ahx yes I checked 3 times..

Comment: @DrBwts I edit my Question. thanks!

Comment: its just pycharm error.. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just `PyCharm` Error.
`PyCharm` represents 'Can't find'.
but I Run my code, and its works well..